# Android: logging of published application

Tags: android

My application is going to be published in the market. I want  to know if is there any standard lib or procedure we can follow  for collecting logs of published apps.It should  not only collect the crash logs but also have to log apps critical events  and send to a predefined backend server. And my source code is obsucated using proguard.

Please suggest an efficient way if anyone has done it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're after **free and open source** check out the following lib: [ACRA](http://acra.ch/).

**What is ACRA?**

ACRA is a library enabling Android Application to automatically post their crash reports to a GoogleDoc form(now deprecated, but they instead use [Acralyzer](https://github.com/ACRA/acralyzer), which is much better). It is targetted to android applications developers to help them get data from their applications when they crash or behave erroneously.

[Here](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) you can find their GitHub page which lists all the features of ACRA if you want to decide if this is for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
   I want to know if is there any standard lib or procedure we can follow for collecting 
logs of published apps.It should not only collect the crash logs but also have to log apps 
critical events and send to a predefined backend server.
```

There is an open Source Library called **Apache** `log4j`. **So by using this Api you can store the all kind of Log into a Text or .Xml file and will be stored in your given path.**

You can find the document [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html)

You can download jar from [Here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/download.html)

And if you released your application then **you can get the Crash log on Google Play Developer Console.**

Or else you can use **Android Crash report using ACRA** to get the Crash log in terms of `Excel`

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Hockey App](http://hockeyapp.net/features/) for retrieving crash reports from users. You can use this [link](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-android/hockeyapp-for-android-sdk) also